# \synctex=1 being an ‘Undefined control sequence’

Tags: mactex, forward-inverse-search, learning

I'm still pretty new to LaTeX; and on my home computer, I've got `lualatex` set up with my first few (pretty simple) LaTeX documents, Skim.app on OS X for viewing, etc etc etc …

… but now that I've cloned that git repository on my laptop, installed the same version of the MacTeX distribution (no custom or special configuration on either!), I'm getting this error with the [same file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/Homework/5fedba69/CS330/Exercise-2.tex) that compiles fine on my home computer:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./Exercise-2.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \synctex
          =1
?
```

The first few lines of that being,

```
\synctex=1
\documentclass[
   paper=a4,
   fontsize=11pt,
   parskip=no,
   fleqn
]{scrartcl}

...
```

Am I using the `synctex` declaration incorrectly, somehow, or …

Comment: You need to pass that option via the command line as part of the compiler, not your source code. That is, `lualatex -synctex=1 <file>`.

Comment: I mean, the \synctex syntax is mentioned [here](http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php?title=SyncTeX); and it definitely works without any flags on my desktop … (I don't use `rubber` or anything yet; I'm still at the point in my TeX career where I literally run `lualatex *.tex` in my homework directory, heh.)

Comment: That may be specific to Vim LaTeX. Is that what you're using? If not, does it work if you call it using `--synctex=1` from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With LaTeX kernels older than the 2015 release, the primitive should be called as

```
\luatexsynctex=1
```

In the current kernel, the `luatex` prefix has been dismissed.

For a foolproof setting, do

```
\ifdefined\synctex\synctex\else\luatexsynctex\fi=1
```

You see the kernel version at the top of a log file; for instance, the current one prints the following banner:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./testsy.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9n> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
```

and you see the kernel date release after `LaTeX2e`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! How do I know which ‘kernel’ I have, and why might it be different in two downloads of MacTex-2015 downloaded within a couple days of one another?

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE I added the information; several other primitives used to be called with the `luatex` prefix.